# regex to match a pattern and then delete it from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I am currently facing a problem. I am trying to write a regex code in order to match a pattern in a text file, and after finding it, remove it from the current text.

```
# Reading the file data and store it 

with open('file.txt','r+') as f:
    file = f.read()
print(file)
```

Here is my text when printed

```
'{\n\tINFO\tDATA_NUMBER\t974\n\t{\n\t\tDAT_CQFD\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tsome random text \t787878\n\t\t}\n\t\tDATA_TO_MATCH\n\t\t{\n\t\t1\tbunch of characters \t985\n\t\t2\tbunch of data\t\t78\n\t\t}\n\t}\n\tINFO\tDATA_CATCHME\t123\n\t{\n\t\t3\tbunch of characters \n\t\t2\tbunch of datas\n\t}\n\tINFO\tDATA_INTACT\t\t456\n\t{\n\t\t3\tbunch of numbers \n\t\t2\tbunch of texts\n\t}\n\n'
```

Here is a picture of the same text opened with an editor :
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctSW1.png)
I would like to match / search DATA_TO_MATCH and then look for the last closed bracket " } "
and remove everything between this close bracket and the next one included.
And I would like to do the same for DATA_CATCHME.

here is the expected result :

```
'{\n\tINFO\tDATA_NUMBER\t974\n\t{\n\t\tDATA_CQFD\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tsome random text \t787878\n\t\t}\n\n\t}\n\tINFO\tDATA_INTACT\t\t456\n\t{\n\t\t3\tbunch of numbers \n\t\t2\tbunch of texts\n\t}\n\n}\n'
```

Here is a picture of the same text result opened with an editor :
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMZ9e.png)

I tried some

```
import re
#find the DATA_TO_MATCH
re.findall(r".*DATA_TO_MATCH",file)  

#find the DATA_CATCHME
re.findall(r".*DATA_CATCHME",file)  

#supposed to find everything before the closed bracket "}"  
re.findall(r"(?=.*})[^}]*",file)
```

But I am not very familiar with regex and re, and i can't get what i want from it,
and I guess when it's found I will use

```
re.sub(my_patern,'', text)
```

to remove it from my text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick here is to use the `re.MULTILINE` flag, which will span across lines. You should also use `re.sub` directly rather than `re.findall`.

The regex itself is simple once you understand it. You look for any characters until `DATA_TO_MATCH`, then chew up any whitespace that may exist (hence the `*`), read a `{`, then read all characters that aren't a `}`, and finally consume the `}`. It's a very similar tactic for the second one.

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    file = f.read()

# find the DATA_TO_MATCH
file = re.sub(r".*DATA_TO_MATCH\s*{[^}]*}", "", file, flags=re.MULTILINE)

# find the DATA_CATCHME
file = re.sub(r".*DATA_CATCHME[^{]*{[^}]*}", "", file, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(file)
```